# Generate slope field of a function with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to graph the slope field of the function: `(x-y)/(x+y)`. Here's what I've got so far:

```tex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    view={0}{90},
    xmax=1, xmin=0,
    ymax=0.6, ymin=-0.6,
    domain=0:1,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    axis line style={<->},
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    grid style={solid,gray!40},
    ticks=none,
    ]
    \addplot3[
      gray,
      quiver={
        u={1},
        v={(x-y)/(x+y)},
        scale arrows=0.3,
      }] (x,y,0);
      % \addplot[thick,red,domain=-10:10,samples=1000] {(x-y)/(x+y)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But this is what it looks like:

[image: output-graph]

I want it to look like this:

[image: how-i-want-it-to-look-like]

How can I graph a function with `x` and `y` terms in it with `\addplot`? When you uncomment the line in the code provided, it gives you an error saying:

```
! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, you can't use 'y' in this context. PGFPlots ex
pected to sample a line, not a mesh. Please use the [mesh] option combined with
 [samples y>0] and [domain y!=0:0] to indicate a twodimensional input domain.

See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.28 ...domain=-10:10,samples=1000] {(x-y)/(x+y)};
                                                  
?
```

Lastly, how can I make the length of all the lines in the slope field constant like in the picture above?